# how to cancel the vba followhyperlink?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, hyperlink

I have an excel worksheet with some hyperlinks. Some of them are email addresses.
When a user clicks a hyperlink, I determine whether or not it is an email, using `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)` and `Target.Address like "mailto:*"`

What I want now is to ***cancel the default hyperlink behavior*** and open the email client myself, programmatically. That way, I can provide a default message and add attachments.

I tried using `Cancel = True` but it doesn't work.
I prefer not to mess with custom hyperlinks because excel generates links to email automatically.

Is it even possible?
Opening the hyperlink seems to happen on another thread.

Comment: This seems to be a challenging problem.  My guess would be that you'd have to hook up your own custom subroutine with the FollowHyperlink event, but I haven't found one resource describing this.  I tried to change everything I could think of, and the click still brought up the link's destination.  As a workaround, you could probably turn all of the hyperlinks in the document to plain text and find the ones for which you are looking.

Comment: Will have to try that if nothing else works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **cannot prevent** a click from following the hyperlink. You can test by yourself by setting a breakpoint in the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` sub. Excel follow the link **before** executing the code.

I **can't see any event procedure** that would help interfere and prevent the behavior.

Another tip i could give is to [prevent Excel from creating hyperlinks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291209) or to do it by vba with a `Worksheet_Change` event.
Next, you could intercept a peuso-click with a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and check if the cell contains a mail address.

Last but not least, if you do know that the **e-mail client is Outlook**, you can probably get the newly created mail to add attachments, recipients, message...

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.

But I do indeed know that the client is outlook. Do you know how I could get a reference to the newly created email?

Comment: Maybe you could check the draft folder ? http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2008/04/check-outlook-drafts-folder-for.html. For better answers, you could ask a new question and link it here, so that SO users will have a look at the tag:vba or tag:outlook-vba :)