# How to disable following hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible (perhaps with a VBA macro) to disable Excel from automatically following hyperlinks in the spreadsheet?

Excel's default, which seems not changeable and is very highly annoying, is "click to follow, hold to edit". I would be perfectly happy with a macro that would intercept any "follow the link" signals and either ignore them or convert to "edit cell", but my VBA experience is quite rudimentary, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Some solutions I have been able to find involve:

- writing a macro to convert all links into plain text,
- setting autocorrect options to prevent new ones from being created

I would prefer not to go that route.

Comment: why the aversion to a macro to convert links to plain text - readonly access?  It's one line of code - Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete, much less fragile and involved than intercepting 'follow the link' which from my limited look at it may not be interceptable.

Comment: Are you referring to http and mailto links? If you never want to follow hyperlinks, turn off the setting that converts them into hyperlinks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to cancel the vba followhyperlink?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829744/how-to-cancel-the-vba-followhyperlink)

Comment: The potential workaround I can suggest is complex - use the `Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink` event to trap then close the newly created Internt window.

Comment: + 1 @brettdj: Yes, I am afraid that is the only way which I also know. In fact I had started writing a sample code and got stuck. I was able to manage "mailto:" / "web links" but the place where I got stuck was in case the url was a "Redirect Url" There I was stuck finding the window handle :D Too complex for my liking! If the macros are disabled or `Application.EnableEvents = False` then the entire thing goes for a waste...

Comment: Thanks brettdj and Siddharth!! Haven't had a chance to try this yet but I definitely will, and post update.

Comment: 2 Jim: yes that would be easier and less fragile, but these are pretty massive spreadsheets that are used and updated on regular basis by multiple people (as well as robots). I considered that, but no.

Comment: This is a big question I've had for a while.  Removing the hyperlinks is not an option, as this is a spreadsheet used by dozens of people across three different companies, many of which need to be able to click those links.  All I want to do is switch the default from hold-to-select to hold-to-follow.  Why is this so impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the answer is a simple as this... I use this myself as a button in my quick lauch bar...

```
Sub removehyperlink()
    Selection.Hyperlinks.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP specifically stated he doesn't want to just remove the hyperlinks.

Comment: Yeah this is nice, but I am really looking for a different solution here.