# Avoid triggering the mailto hyperlink in excel-vba

Tags: vba, email, excel

Good morning everybody. Thanks for your attention and apologies in advance if this has been asked before.

I have a spreadsheet with several contacts and emails. At work, we send emails to these contacts on a regular basis, tailored through some specific templates. I've created a code that, when you click a mailto: hyperlink, a small form with a dropdown menu shows up so we can select the template to use, and when clicking a command button, it composes an email using Outloook, populating the body of the email with the template and the contact, company name, subject, etc.

All of that works perfectly.

However, it not only opens the userform; it also opens a new, blank email, as it would without the code.

Is there any way to prevent that from happening? To only execute my code when clicking the email address?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you run code to turn off all hyperlinks when the worksheet is loaded? Something like: ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Delete. Or does the hyperlink kick off your code to load your custom form? (Not sure what OnClick event you're using to open your form.)

Comment: Yes, clicking the hyperlink shows the form, which has a CommandButton; by clicking the button, it runs a macro that does the rest. Here's the code that shows the form:

    Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
If Target.Range.Address = ActiveCell.Address Then
UserForm1.Show
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Comment: Excellent suggestion, @SiddharthRout. That worked perfectly.

I checked if instr(target.text,"@") <> 0 then show my userform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot cancel the FollowHyperlink. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829744/how-to-cancel-the-vba-followhyperlink) has been answered before.

**Alternative**

Use `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` event and trap the particular range which has email and in this event launch your form. Let's say you email hyperlinks are in range `B2:B30`. Then do this

**A**) Remove all hyperlinks from those cells. See [This](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-select-edit-or-delete-a-hyperlink-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e#bmremovehyperlink)

**B**) (*Optional*) If you want to give them a hyperlink appearance then color the font of the cells as Blue and Underline it.

**C**) Paste this code in the worksheet code area

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B30")) Is Nothing Then
        MyForm.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)` be more appropriate for this? [Worksheet.FollowHyperlink Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838843.aspx)

Comment: That is the first thought that would come to mind but unfortunately that will not work. It's mentioned in the first link as well in my answer.

Comment: Aplogies - I was sure that I had done something along these lines with Worksheet_FollowHyperlink but it appears that I am more delusional than normal today.

Comment: `I am more delusional than normal today` You are not alone. Count me in ;)